# How can i get user role in my actions

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I am using zf2 with this two modules
 (zfc-user, bjyauthorize) and i want to get the user role from my actions

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, I have removed the information not directly related to your question... you're not left with much. Could you please clarify and expand your question and include the code you've managed to create so far to do this.

Comment: please explain more on your concern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

#### In your Controller

```
$viewmodel = new ViewModel();
$authorize = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface');
$roles = $authorize->getIdentityRoles();

$viewmodel->setVariable("roles", $roles);
return $viewmodel;
```

#### In your view script

```
<?php var_dump($this->roles); ?>
```